# How to detect html file is loading android webview or android browser

Tags: android, html, url, webview

I create one application in html. In that application I need to implement one functionality.

2 cases I have

Case 1: If my application is loaded in browser i need to redirect to one specific point

Case 2: If my application is loaded from android WebView container mean i need to redirect to another specific point.

Is it possible ?, If possible Share the me the code or suggest me the idea
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use **user agent** to detect whether it is a browser or a WebView. Refer to [WebView on Android](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent#webview_user_agent) for the UA strings on different versions of Android.

To get the user agent in Javascript, use `navigator.userAgent`.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I already try the userAgent, It return same value for WebView as well as Browser. The version only change.